# windows phone app to post update on users wall using Facebook C# SDK

Tags: windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I want my windows phone app login user in to facebook using OAuth 2.0 and to post update on users wall. Pls help me out with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to get started with the Facebook C# SDK is to look at the Windows Phone 7 specific sample [here](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/585d61400fcf#Samples%2fCS-WP7%2fFacebookLoginPage.xaml.cs)

Comment: @oliver Payen : thanks for your timely response, but unfortunately i am unable to find Samples folder. even i downloaded the facebook package from NuGet

Thanks

Comment: Seems like they remove the samples from the package. I updated my answer with a link to the old Codeplex project that contains the sample code.